# Do you capitalize "second" or "third" etc, as in "William Jones the second"?

Tags: capitalization

Do you capitalize "second" or "third" etc, as in "William Jones the second"? I realize I could avoid the whole issue by saying "William Jones II," but still.

Comment: You would normally call the son of the original William Jones "William Jones, Jr." (Junior). Subsequent descendants would be William Jones III, William Jones IV, etc. Nobody writes "the third" in any formal context.

Comment: Well, BUT if William is named for his UNCLE rather than his FATHER, then he is the second, not Junior.

Comment: That's not true at all. Nobody but direct descendants and royal successors get the numbered identifiers.

Comment: Wow. This is a really common convention, as outlined on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_(name)#Generational_titles

Comment: (Edit is not working real well for me...) But ANYWAY, my author wants to have this very cleverly named character whose initials are H.E. & he is "the second," so he is "H.E. II"(bwahaha), but then we have to clarify that moniker by stating that he is "Herman Edwards the second." So we want to write out "the second." Thus the question. Kind of a tortured situation, I know, b/c I'm aware that it's not real common for an adult man to go by "the second" whether you use a numeral or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would capitalize any suffix/prefix and title relating to a name if that's how they're known or distinguished.

> Her Majesty Queen Elizabeth the Second.
>
> Alexander the Great.
>
> Conan the Barbarian.